# Trigger Governor Limit : Inline query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com

I am trying to resolve a governor limit challenge with my code. Can anyone help me understand this.

[image: ContactTrigger]

I am getting "Inline query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop" exception.Exception is occurring on "before update". Many thanks !

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please always paste your code and don't use screenshots.

Comment: hint: for line 13-16 you could simply use `ccList.addAll(accObj.contacts);`

Comment: I couldn't find anything odd, in which line does it fail?

Comment: I see a couple of issues here offhand.  You have a query inside of a loop is the biggest issue.  I don't have time for a full answer though.

Comment: As Basti has already mentioned, copy/pasting your code is much preferred over screenshots. Also, including the whole text of the error message **verbatim** helps as well (as well as including some indication in your code as to which line the error is complaining about). Usually, the error you've encountered is an indication of having a certain number of child records in a subquery...but it looks like you're already doing the safe thing, and iterating over child records in a loop (vs the `.addAll()` that Basti suggested). I think more information is required, so please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SOQL For Loop`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm#) syntax to try to avoid this error.  This would look like:

```
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
for(Account acc : [select ID, (select ID from Contact) from Account where ID in :accID])
{
    accList.add(acc);
}
```

Note that there is no requirement to create a `list` of the `Account` records returned, you can just run through each account and perform some action with it.  In your case it looks like you actually need the contacts from these accounts, so you can either nest another for loop over `acc.Contacts` and add contacts inside the second one, or you can get the same `ccList` with the following query:

```
List<Contact> ccList = [select ID from Contact where ParentID in :accIDs];
```

Since it looks like your logic is actually just interested in the count of the contacts, you could save yourself some heap space and just get the count instead:

```
integer relatedContactCount = [select Count() from Contact where ParentID in :accIDs];
```

Comment: As well with this - if you have too many rows - try adding a better filter on whichever query you are receiving this for to help reduce the number of rows that you're returning.